# Why NSURLConnection didReceiveData not be called in background location update

Tags: ios

Please help me, I am coding iOS with background location update and send location data to my server.
below is my code:

```
 #import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    NSLog(@"Went to Background");
       [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
       [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier locationUpdateTaskID = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (locationUpdateTaskID != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
                [app endBackgroundTask:locationUpdateTaskID];
                locationUpdateTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        if ([[locations lastObject] horizontalAccuracy] < 100.0f) {

            NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            mytoken=[userDefaults stringForKey:@"mytoken"];
            if (mytoken==nil) {
                mytoken=@"";
            }
            mybgtype=[userDefaults stringForKey:@"mybgtype"];
            if (mybgtype==nil) {
                mybgtype=@"all";
                [userDefaults setObject:mybgtype forKey:@"mybgtype"];
                [userDefaults synchronize];
            }


            CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
            CLLocation *oldLocation;
            if (locations.count > 1) {
                oldLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:locations.count-2];
            } else {
                oldLocation = nil;
            }

            NSString *NowLng=[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:newLocation.coordinate.longitude] stringValue];
            NSString *NowLat=[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:newLocation.coordinate.latitude] stringValue];

            UILocalNotification *scheduleAlert;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
            scheduleAlert=[[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            scheduleAlert.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
            scheduleAlert.fireDate=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
            scheduleAlert.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            scheduleAlert.repeatInterval=NSDayCalendarUnit;
            scheduleAlert.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            scheduleAlert.alertBody=NowLat;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:scheduleAlert];

            if ([mybgtype isEqualToString:@"n"]) {
            } else {

                [self LoadTaskMyBg:newLocation];
            }


        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (locationUpdateTaskID != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
                [app endBackgroundTask:locationUpdateTaskID];
                locationUpdateTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    });
}


-(void) LoadTaskMyBg:(CLLocation *)newLocation
{

    NSString *mylat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *mylng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    NSLog(@"task 1");


    receivedDataMyBg=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];

    NSString * urlString;

    urlString = @"https://www.xx.xx/xx.cshtml";



    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *parameterString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@", @"pp=a&tt=",@"aa",@"&mylat=",mylat,@"&mylng=",mylng,@"&myalt=",@"0"];

    NSData * postData = [parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    connMyBg = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSLog(@"task 1a");
    NSLog(@"%@",parameterString);


    if (connMyBg==nil) {
        NSLog(@"task 1e");
        return;
    }


}


- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace{
    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{
    //NSLog(@"received authen challenge");

    NSLog(@"task challenge");

    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

    if (connection==connMyBg) {
        [receivedDataMyBg setLength:0];

        NSLog(@"task connect receive");
    }

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    //NSLog(@"got data %@", [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]);
    if (connection==connMyBg) {
        [receivedDataMyBg appendData:data];
    }

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"error");

    if (connection==connMyBg) {

    }

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    if (connection==connMyBg) {

        NSLog(@"task 2");

        NSString *response;
        NSError *error;
        response=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedDataMyBg encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData* data = [response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *JSONDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];



        if([[JSONDic objectForKey:@"bnum"] isEqualToString:@""])
        {

        } else {
            UILocalNotification *scheduleAlert;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
            scheduleAlert=[[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            scheduleAlert.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
            scheduleAlert.fireDate=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
            scheduleAlert.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            scheduleAlert.repeatInterval=NSDayCalendarUnit;
            scheduleAlert.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            scheduleAlert.alertBody=@"TEST:OK";
        }

        NSLog(@"%@",[JSONDic objectForKey:@"bnum"]);



    }

}

@end
```

I can get log: "task 1a" ! but why I can't receive "task connect receive" ????
What should I do ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Do any other `NSURLConnection` callback methods work?

Comment: thanks for Timucin,
I use another way, It's work :
NSString* pp =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.xxxx.xx/xx.cshtml?x=%@&xx=%@&mylat=%.4f&mylng=%.4f&myalt=%.4f",@"xx",mytoken, newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude,0.0];
                
                NSURL* response =[NSURL URLWithString:pp];
                NSString* response_str =[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@, response of report=%@", pp, response_str);

I can get response_str
But, How it can pass https?? But it just work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a delegate for either NSURLConnection or CLLocationManager you'll need to create them as properties with a strong reference. Otherwise the delegate implementation will not get called. Since you did not provide the part where you declared those that may be the problem.

Comment: Dear Sjors,Thanks for reply.
I already delegate self in code:
connMyBg = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

doesn't it ?

Comment: I declared in AppDelegate.h => NSURLConnection *connMyBg;

Comment: Yes but did you define it as an instance variable or as a strong property?

Answer (score 0):

NSString* pp =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxx.xx/xx.cshtml, newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude,0.0];

NSURL* response =[NSURL URLWithString:pp];

NSString* response_str =[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@, response of report=%@", pp, response_str);

---

If I rewrite the code in didUpdateLocations as above, 
I can get response_str and it is correct! 
But question is: How can it pass ssl https without be challenged ?? 
even if it ready work very well!